# County-level plot has gap between the States

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to plot the geographical distribution of wheat production using a county-level data set.

In order to create the data set, I combined a data set of county-level fips code with unique latitude-longitude for each fips code, with a data set of county-level wheat production.

I do not know why, it shows gaps between States, instead of having them connected (figure below)
[image]

```
library(maps)
library(urbnmapr)

g43 <- wheat_corn_insurance1 %>% filter(year==1989) %>% filter(wheat==1)%>%
        ggplot(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group = state, fill = stateproduction/1000)) + 
        geom_polygon(color = NA) + 
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + 
        labs(title = "County-Level Choropleth Map", 
        subtitle = "Wheat Production (thousand bu), 1989")

g43
```

I tried using the urbnmapr package as well, but I received a similar result.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Maybe there is no data in those empty Spaces. Are you sure there should be geographical data there ?. Or maybe there is no wheat data there.

Comment: Not all counties have data, but I have grouped data at the State level and asked to fill it with the state-level production in the ggplot. It's why I expected to see states completely colored.